# Ipod crashes after transfering music from Rhythmbox

Tags: rhythmbox, ipod

I have been using Rhythmbox for a long time to transfer music to my 3.1 Ipod Touch 3rd Gen, however after recently transferring an album my music app refuses to load. Sometimes it instantly crashes, sometimes I get a song list and then a freeze, sometimes only the basic GUI comes up, and other times I get a "Updating Library" which crashes or sits there endlessly. Any thoughts on fixing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue with my iPod touch. The only fix I could find was to connect it to iTunes. The database schema the Touch uses is somewhat obscure; it's possible that Rhythmbox's developers haven't gotten it down pat yet.